# R -classification =Two variables to be used in classification

Tags: r

The file name is-

```
data1<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\ankit\\Desktop\\R\\Wholesalecustomersdata.csv")
```

the output code I entered for a problem is-

```
Wholesalecustomersdata %>% group_by(Region,channel)%>% summarize(AverageMilk=mean(Milk),MaxMilk=max(Milk),AverageGrocery=mean(Grocery),sdGrocery=sd(Grocery))
```

when I am trying the run the above code ,R is giving the following error- 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :

> object 'Wholesalecustomersdata' not found

Question - I have to create a report which is having data like this-

```
Channel Region  Fresh   Milk    Grocery Frozen  Detergents_Paper    Delicassen
2   3   12669   9656    7561    214 2674    1338
2   3   7057    9810    9568    1762    3293    1776
2   3   6353    8808    7684    2405    3516    7844
1   3   13265   1196    4221    6404    507 1788
2   3   22615   5410    7198    3915    1777    5185
2   3   9413    8259    5126    666 1795    1451
2   3   12126   3199    6975    480 3140    545
2   3   7579    4956    9426    1669    3321    2566
1   3   5963    3648    6192    425 1716    750
2   3   6006    11093   18881   1159    7425    2098
2   3   3366    5403    12974   4400    5977    1744
2   3   13146   1124    4523    1420    549 497
2   3   31714   12319   11757   287 3881    2931
2   3   21217   6208    14982   3095    6707    602
2   3   24653   9465    12091   294 5058    2168
1   3   10253   1114    3821    397 964 412
2   3   1020    8816    12121   134 4508    1080
1   3   5876    6157    2933    839 370 4478
2   3   18601   6327    10099   2205    2767    3181
1   3   7780    2495    9464    669 2518    501
2   3   17546   4519    4602    1066    2259    2124
1   3   5567    871 2010    3383    375 569
1   3   31276   1917    4469    9408    2381    4334
2   3   26373   36423   22019   5154    4337    16523
2   3   22647   9776    13792   2915    4482    5778
2   3   16165   4230    7595    201 4003    57
1   3   9898    961 2861    3151    242 833
1   3   14276   803 3045    485 100 518
2   3   4113    20484   25957   1158    8604    5206
1   3   43088   2100    2609    1200    1107    823
1   3   18815   3610    11107   1148    2134    2963
1   3   2612    4339    3133    2088    820 985
1   3   21632   1318    2886    266 918 405
1   3   29729   4786    7326    6130    361 1083
1   3   1502    1979    2262    425 483 395
2   3   688 5491    11091   833 4239    436
1   3   29955   4362    5428    1729    862 4626
2   3   15168   10556   12477   1920    6506    714
2   3   4591    15729   16709   33  6956    433
1   3   56159   555 902 10002   212 2916
1   3   24025   4332    4757    9510    1145    5864
1   3   19176   3065    5956    2033    2575    2802
2   3   10850   7555    14961   188 6899    46
2   3   630 11095   23998   787 9529    72
2   3   9670    7027    10471   541 4618    65
2   3   5181    22044   21531   1740    7353    4985
2   3   3103    14069   21955   1668    6792    1452
2   3   44466   54259   55571   7782    24171   6465
2   3   11519   6152    10868   584 5121    1476
2   3   4967    21412   28921   1798    13583   1163
1   3   6269    1095    1980    3860    609 2162
1   3   3347    4051    6996    239 1538    301
2   3   40721   3916    5876    532 2587    1278
2   3   491 10473   11532   744 5611    224
1   3   27329   1449    1947    2436    204 1333
1   3   5264    3683    5005    1057    2024    1130
2   3   4098    29892   26866   2616    17740   1340
2   3   5417    9933    10487   38  7572    1282
1   3   13779   1970    1648    596 227 436
1   3   6137    5360    8040    129 3084    1603
2   3   8590    3045    7854    96  4095    225
2   3   35942   38369   59598   3254    26701   2017
2   3   7823    6245    6544    4154    4074    964
2   3   9396    11601   15775   2896    7677    1295
1   3   4760    1227    3250    3724    1247    1145
2   3   85  20959   45828   36  24231   1423
1   3   9   1534    7417    175 3468    27
2   3   19913   6759    13462   1256    5141    834
1   3   2446    7260    3993    5870    788 3095
1   3   8352    2820    1293    779 656 144
1   3   16705   2037    3202    10643   116 1365
1   3   18291   1266    21042   5373    4173    14472
1   3   4420    5139    2661    8872    1321    181
2   3   19899   5332    8713    8132    764 648
2   3   8190    6343    9794    1285    1901    1780
1   3   20398   1137    3   4407    3   975
1   3   717 3587    6532    7530    529 894
2   3   12205   12697   28540   869 12034   1009
1   3   10766   1175    2067    2096    301 167
1   3   1640    3259    3655    868 1202    1653
1   3   7005    829 3009    430 610 529
2   3   219 9540    14403   283 7818    156
2   3   10362   9232    11009   737 3537    2342
1   3   20874   1563    1783    2320    550 772
2   3   11867   3327    4814    1178    3837    120
2   3   16117   46197   92780   1026    40827   2944
2   3   22925   73498   32114   987 20070   903
1   3   43265   5025    8117    6312    1579    14351
1   3   7864    542 4042    9735    165 46
1   3   24904   3836    5330    3443    454 3178
1   3   11405   596 1638    3347    69  360
1   3   12754   2762    2530    8693    627 1117
2   3   9198    27472   32034   3232    18906   5130
1   3   11314   3090    2062    35009   71  2698
2   3   5626    12220   11323   206 5038    244
1   3   3   2920    6252    440 223 709
2   3   23  2616    8118    145 3874    217
1   3   403 254 610 774 54  63
1   3   503 112 778 895 56  132
1   3   9658    2182    1909    5639    215 323
2   3   11594   7779    12144   3252    8035    3029
2   3   1420    10810   16267   1593    6766    1838
2   3   2932    6459    7677    2561    4573    1386
1   3   56082   3504    8906    18028   1480    2498
1   3   14100   2132    3445    1336    1491    548
1   3   15587   1014    3970    910 139 1378
2   3   1454    6337    10704   133 6830    1831
2   3   8797    10646   14886   2471    8969    1438
2   3   1531    8397    6981    247 2505    1236
2   3   1406    16729   28986   673 836 3
1   3   11818   1648    1694    2276    169 1647
2   3   12579   11114   17569   805 6457    1519
1   3   19046   2770    2469    8853    483 2708
1   3   14438   2295    1733    3220    585 1561
1   3   18044   1080    2000    2555    118 1266
1   3   11134   793 2988    2715    276 610
1   3   11173   2521    3355    1517    310 222
1   3   6990    3880    5380    1647    319 1160
1   3   20049   1891    2362    5343    411 933
1   3   8258    2344    2147    3896    266 635
1   3   17160   1200    3412    2417    174 1136
1   3   4020    3234    1498    2395    264 255
1   3   12212   201 245 1991    25  860
2   3   11170   10769   8814    2194    1976    143
1   3   36050   1642    2961    4787    500 1621
1   3   76237   3473    7102    16538   778 918
1   3   19219   1840    1658    8195    349 483
2   3   21465   7243    10685   880 2386    2749
1   3   140 8847    3823    142 1062    3
1   3   42312   926 1510    1718    410 1819
1   3   7149    2428    699 6316    395 911
1   3   2101    589 314 346 70  310
1   3   14903   2032    2479    576 955 328
1   3   9434    1042    1235    436 256 396
1   3   7388    1882    2174    720 47  537
1   3   6300    1289    2591    1170    199 326
1   3   4625    8579    7030    4575    2447    1542
1   3   3087    8080    8282    661 721 36
1   3   13537   4257    5034    155 249 3271
1   3   5387    4979    3343    825 637 929
1   3   17623   4280    7305    2279    960 2616
1   3   30379   13252   5189    321 51  1450
1   3   37036   7152    8253    2995    20  3
1   3   10405   1596    1096    8425    399 318
1   3   18827   3677    1988    118 516 201
2   3   22039   8384    34792   42  12591   4430
1   3   7769    1936    2177    926 73  520
1   3   9203    3373    2707    1286    1082    526
1   3   5924    584 542 4052    283 434
1   3   31812   1433    1651    800 113 1440
1   3   16225   1825    1765    853 170 1067
1   3   1289    3328    2022    531 255 1774
1   3   18840   1371    3135    3001    352 184
1   3   3463    9250    2368    779 302 1627
1   3   622 55  137 75  7   8
2   3   1989    10690   19460   233 11577   2153
2   3   3830    5291    14855   317 6694    3182
1   3   17773   1366    2474    3378    811 418
2   3   2861    6570    9618    930 4004    1682
2   3   355 7704    14682   398 8077    303
2   3   1725    3651    12822   824 4424    2157
1   3   12434   540 283 1092    3   2233
1   3   15177   2024    3810    2665    232 610
2   3   5531    15726   26870   2367    13726   446
2   3   5224    7603    8584    2540    3674    238
2   3   15615   12653   19858   4425    7108    2379
2   3   4822    6721    9170    993 4973    3637
1   3   2926    3195    3268    405 1680    693
1   3   5809    735 803 1393    79  429
1   3   5414    717 2155    2399    69  750
2   3   260 8675    13430   1116    7015    323
2   3   200 25862   19816   651 8773    6250
1   3   955 5479    6536    333 2840    707
2   3   514 7677    19805   937 9836    716
1   3   286 1208    5241    2515    153 1442
2   3   2343    7845    11874   52  4196    1697
1   3   45640   6958    6536    7368    1532    230
1   3   12759   7330    4533    1752    20  2631
1   3   11002   7075    4945    1152    120 395
1   3   3157    4888    2500    4477    273 2165
1   3   12356   6036    8887    402 1382    2794
1   3   112151  29627   18148   16745   4948    8550
1   3   694 8533    10518   443 6907    156
1   3   36847   43950   20170   36534   239 47943
1   3   327 918 4710    74  334 11
1   3   8170    6448    1139    2181    58  247
1   3   3009    521 854 3470    949 727
1   3   2438    8002    9819    6269    3459    3
2   3   8040    7639    11687   2758    6839    404
2   3   834 11577   11522   275 4027    1856
1   3   16936   6250    1981    7332    118 64
1   3   13624   295 1381    890 43  84
1   3   5509    1461    2251    547 187 409
2   3   180 3485    20292   959 5618    666
1   3   7107    1012    2974    806 355 1142
1   3   17023   5139    5230    7888    330 1755
1   1   30624   7209    4897    18711   763 2876
2   1   2427    7097    10391   1127    4314    1468
1   1   11686   2154    6824    3527    592 697
1   1   9670    2280    2112    520 402 347
2   1   3067    13240   23127   3941    9959    731
2   1   4484    14399   24708   3549    14235   1681
1   1   25203   11487   9490    5065    284 6854
1   1   583 685 2216    469 954 18
1   1   1956    891 5226    1383    5   1328
2   1   1107    11711   23596   955 9265    710
1   1   6373    780 950 878 288 285
2   1   2541    4737    6089    2946    5316    120
1   1   1537    3748    5838    1859    3381    806
2   1   5550    12729   16767   864 12420   797
1   1   18567   1895    1393    1801    244 2100
2   1   12119   28326   39694   4736    19410   2870
1   1   7291    1012    2062    1291    240 1775
1   1   3317    6602    6861    1329    3961    1215
2   1   2362    6551    11364   913 5957    791
1   1   2806    10765   15538   1374    5828    2388
2   1   2532    16599   36486   179 13308   674
1   1   18044   1475    2046    2532    130 1158
2   1   18  7504    15205   1285    4797    6372
1   1   4155    367 1390    2306    86  130
1   1   14755   899 1382    1765    56  749
1   1   5396    7503    10646   91  4167    239
1   1   5041    1115    2856    7496    256 375
2   1   2790    2527    5265    5612    788 1360
1   1   7274    659 1499    784 70  659
1   1   12680   3243    4157    660 761 786
2   1   20782   5921    9212    1759    2568    1553
1   1   4042    2204    1563    2286    263 689
1   1   1869    577 572 950 4762    203
1   1   8656    2746    2501    6845    694 980
2   1   11072   5989    5615    8321    955 2137
1   1   2344    10678   3828    1439    1566    490
1   1   25962   1780    3838    638 284 834
1   1   964 4984    3316    937 409 7
1   1   15603   2703    3833    4260    325 2563
1   1   1838    6380    2824    1218    1216    295
1   1   8635    820 3047    2312    415 225
1   1   18692   3838    593 4634    28  1215
1   1   7363    475 585 1112    72  216
1   1   47493   2567    3779    5243    828 2253
1   1   22096   3575    7041    11422   343 2564
1   1   24929   1801    2475    2216    412 1047
1   1   18226   659 2914    3752    586 578
1   1   11210   3576    5119    561 1682    2398
1   1   6202    7775    10817   1183    3143    1970
2   1   3062    6154    13916   230 8933    2784
1   1   8885    2428    1777    1777    430 610
1   1   13569   346 489 2077    44  659
1   1   15671   5279    2406    559 562 572
1   1   8040    3795    2070    6340    918 291
1   1   3191    1993    1799    1730    234 710
2   1   6134    23133   33586   6746    18594   5121
1   1   6623    1860    4740    7683    205 1693
1   1   29526   7961    16966   432 363 1391
1   1   10379   17972   4748    4686    1547    3265
1   1   31614   489 1495    3242    111 615
1   1   11092   5008    5249    453 392 373
1   1   8475    1931    1883    5004    3593    987
1   1   56083   4563    2124    6422    730 3321
1   1   53205   4959    7336    3012    967 818
1   1   9193    4885    2157    327 780 548
1   1   7858    1110    1094    6818    49  287
1   1   23257   1372    1677    982 429 655
1   1   2153    1115    6684    4324    2894    411
2   1   1073    9679    15445   61  5980    1265
1   1   5909    23527   13699   10155   830 3636
2   1   572 9763    22182   2221    4882    2563
1   1   20893   1222    2576    3975    737 3628
2   1   11908   8053    19847   1069    6374    698
1   1   15218   258 1138    2516    333 204
1   1   4720    1032    975 5500    197 56
1   1   2083    5007    1563    1120    147 1550
1   1   514 8323    6869    529 93  1040
1   3   36817   3045    1493    4802    210 1824
1   3   894 1703    1841    744 759 1153
1   3   680 1610    223 862 96  379
1   3   27901   3749    6964    4479    603 2503
1   3   9061    829 683 16919   621 139
1   3   11693   2317    2543    5845    274 1409
2   3   17360   6200    9694    1293    3620    1721
1   3   3366    2884    2431    977 167 1104
2   3   12238   7108    6235    1093    2328    2079
1   3   49063   3965    4252    5970    1041    1404
1   3   25767   3613    2013    10303   314 1384
1   3   68951   4411    12609   8692    751 2406
1   3   40254   640 3600    1042    436 18
1   3   7149    2247    1242    1619    1226    128
1   3   15354   2102    2828    8366    386 1027
1   3   16260   594 1296    848 445 258
1   3   42786   286 471 1388    32  22
1   3   2708    2160    2642    502 965 1522
1   3   6022    3354    3261    2507    212 686
1   3   2838    3086    4329    3838    825 1060
2   2   3996    11103   12469   902 5952    741
1   2   21273   2013    6550    909 811 1854
2   2   7588    1897    5234    417 2208    254
1   2   19087   1304    3643    3045    710 898
2   2   8090    3199    6986    1455    3712    531
2   2   6758    4560    9965    934 4538    1037
1   2   444 879 2060    264 290 259
2   2   16448   6243    6360    824 2662    2005
2   2   5283    13316   20399   1809    8752    172
2   2   2886    5302    9785    364 6236    555
2   2   2599    3688    13829   492 10069   59
2   2   161 7460    24773   617 11783   2410
2   2   243 12939   8852    799 3909    211
2   2   6468    12867   21570   1840    7558    1543
1   2   17327   2374    2842    1149    351 925
1   2   6987    1020    3007    416 257 656
2   2   918 20655   13567   1465    6846    806
1   2   7034    1492    2405    12569   299 1117
1   2   29635   2335    8280    3046    371 117
2   2   2137    3737    19172   1274    17120   142
1   2   9784    925 2405    4447    183 297
1   2   10617   1795    7647    1483    857 1233
2   2   1479    14982   11924   662 3891    3508
1   2   7127    1375    2201    2679    83  1059
1   2   1182    3088    6114    978 821 1637
1   2   11800   2713    3558    2121    706 51
2   2   9759    25071   17645   1128    12408   1625
1   2   1774    3696    2280    514 275 834
1   2   9155    1897    5167    2714    228 1113
1   2   15881   713 3315    3703    1470    229
1   2   13360   944 11593   915 1679    573
1   2   25977   3587    2464    2369    140 1092
1   2   32717   16784   13626   60869   1272    5609
1   2   4414    1610    1431    3498    387 834
1   2   542 899 1664    414 88  522
1   2   16933   2209    3389    7849    210 1534
1   2   5113    1486    4583    5127    492 739
1   2   9790    1786    5109    3570    182 1043
2   2   11223   14881   26839   1234    9606    1102
1   2   22321   3216    1447    2208    178 2602
2   2   8565    4980    67298   131 38102   1215
2   2   16823   928 2743    11559   332 3486
2   2   27082   6817    10790   1365    4111    2139
1   2   13970   1511    1330    650 146 778
1   2   9351    1347    2611    8170    442 868
1   2   3   333 7021    15601   15  550
1   2   2617    1188    5332    9584    573 1942
2   3   381 4025    9670    388 7271    1371
2   3   2320    5763    11238   767 5162    2158
1   3   255 5758    5923    349 4595    1328
2   3   1689    6964    26316   1456    15469   37
1   3   3043    1172    1763    2234    217 379
1   3   1198    2602    8335    402 3843    303
2   3   2771    6939    15541   2693    6600    1115
2   3   27380   7184    12311   2809    4621    1022
1   3   3428    2380    2028    1341    1184    665
2   3   5981    14641   20521   2005    12218   445
1   3   3521    1099    1997    1796    173 995
2   3   1210    10044   22294   1741    12638   3137
1   3   608 1106    1533    830 90  195
2   3   117 6264    21203   228 8682    1111
1   3   14039   7393    2548    6386    1333    2341
1   3   190 727 2012    245 184 127
1   3   22686   134 218 3157    9   548
2   3   37  1275    22272   137 6747    110
1   3   759 18664   1660    6114    536 4100
1   3   796 5878    2109    340 232 776
1   3   19746   2872    2006    2601    468 503
1   3   4734    607 864 1206    159 405
1   3   2121    1601    2453    560 179 712
1   3   4627    997 4438    191 1335    314
1   3   2615    873 1524    1103    514 468
2   3   4692    6128    8025    1619    4515    3105
1   3   9561    2217    1664    1173    222 447
1   3   3477    894 534 1457    252 342
1   3   22335   1196    2406    2046    101 558
1   3   6211    337 683 1089    41  296
2   3   39679   3944    4955    1364    523 2235
1   3   20105   1887    1939    8164    716 790
1   3   3884    3801    1641    876 397 4829
2   3   15076   6257    7398    1504    1916    3113
1   3   6338    2256    1668    1492    311 686
1   3   5841    1450    1162    597 476 70
2   3   3136    8630    13586   5641    4666    1426
1   3   38793   3154    2648    1034    96  1242
1   3   3225    3294    1902    282 68  1114
2   3   4048    5164    10391   130 813 179
1   3   28257   944 2146    3881    600 270
1   3   17770   4591    1617    9927    246 532
1   3   34454   7435    8469    2540    1711    2893
1   3   1821    1364    3450    4006    397 361
1   3   10683   21858   15400   3635    282 5120
1   3   11635   922 1614    2583    192 1068
1   3   1206    3620    2857    1945    353 967
1   3   20918   1916    1573    1960    231 961
1   3   9785    848 1172    1677    200 406
1   3   9385    1530    1422    3019    227 684
1   3   3352    1181    1328    5502    311 1000
1   3   2647    2761    2313    907 95  1827
1   3   518 4180    3600    659 122 654
1   3   23632   6730    3842    8620    385 819
1   3   12377   865 3204    1398    149 452
1   3   9602    1316    1263    2921    841 290
2   3   4515    11991   9345    2644    3378    2213
1   3   11535   1666    1428    6838    64  743
1   3   11442   1032    582 5390    74  247
1   3   9612    577 935 1601    469 375
1   3   4446    906 1238    3576    153 1014
1   3   27167   2801    2128    13223   92  1902
1   3   26539   4753    5091    220 10  340
1   3   25606   11006   4604    127 632 288
1   3   18073   4613    3444    4324    914 715
1   3   6884    1046    1167    2069    593 378
1   3   25066   5010    5026    9806    1092    960
2   3   7362    12844   18683   2854    7883    553
2   3   8257    3880    6407    1646    2730    344
1   3   8708    3634    6100    2349    2123    5137
1   3   6633    2096    4563    1389    1860    1892
1   3   2126    3289    3281    1535    235 4365
1   3   97  3605    12400   98  2970    62
1   3   4983    4859    6633    17866   912 2435
1   3   5969    1990    3417    5679    1135    290
2   3   7842    6046    8552    1691    3540    1874
2   3   4389    10940   10908   848 6728    993
1   3   5065    5499    11055   364 3485    1063
2   3   660 8494    18622   133 6740    776
1   3   8861    3783    2223    633 1580    1521
1   3   4456    5266    13227   25  6818    1393
2   3   17063   4847    9053    1031    3415    1784
1   3   26400   1377    4172    830 948 1218
2   3   17565   3686    4657    1059    1803    668
2   3   16980   2884    12232   874 3213    249
1   3   11243   2408    2593    15348   108 1886
1   3   13134   9347    14316   3141    5079    1894
1   3   31012   16687   5429    15082   439 1163
1   3   3047    5970    4910    2198    850 317
1   3   8607    1750    3580    47  84  2501
1   3   3097    4230    16483   575 241 2080
1   3   8533    5506    5160    13486   1377    1498
1   3   21117   1162    4754    269 1328    395
1   3   1982    3218    1493    1541    356 1449
1   3   16731   3922    7994    688 2371    838
1   3   29703   12051   16027   13135   182 2204
1   3   39228   1431    764 4510    93  2346
2   3   14531   15488   30243   437 14841   1867
1   3   10290   1981    2232    1038    168 2125
1   3   2787    1698    2510    65  477 52
```

I have to create a report with average milk, max milk, average grocery, standard deviation of grocery in a systematic way.

Do also suggest why this error is coming?

[image]

Comment: I've re-added the missing image to your question, but I am not sure it adds anything - you might want to remove it, since it duplicates other material.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are reading the file into a variable called `data1`, but then you try to work with a variable called `Wholesalecustomersdata`, which doesn't exist!

Try:

```
Wholesalecustomersdata <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\ankit\\Desktop\\R\\Wholesalecustomersdata.csv")
```

Bonus tip: while you are making changes, that's not a great variable name because it's cumbersome and hard to read

Comment: Thanku so very much for the answer ...Really appreciate it ! M a kinda toddeler in coding stuff thats why it happened ...Thanks once again